# How to translate this code snippet in Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I wanted to modify the cell UI based the documentation mentioned here at [enter link description here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController), but couldn't figure how to translate the `super` part.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is what I have translated:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = super.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Do you subclass `JSQMessagesViewController` ? It would be helpful if you could provide more code btw...

Comment: Yes I do subclass JSQMessagesViewController. I'm not familiar with Obj C. So the sample code here is a bit hard for me to understand.

Comment: Is it recognizing the class ? I.e. no compilation/linking problems ?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question with my translation. It built successfully, but whenever it goes the view, it crashes with this error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Then I noticed that cell is nil, but this function expects to be not nil.

Comment: That's because you are calling it on super's collectionView as opposed to calling the super function. Try the answer I posted below.

Comment: Thanks @the_critic!  I got an error ` Overriding method with selector 'collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:' has incompatible type '(JSQMessagesCollectionView, NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell'` when I copied your code. Do you know why?

Comment: You'll need to provide more code... I looked into the repository, I am pretty sure the answer I gave should work fine. The `JSQMessagesViewController` conforms to a protocol that extends the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol, which means the super method should work fine. I made an edit in my answer, try it that way.

Comment: Just downloaded the library and it seems to compile for me with the code I have posted...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the correct syntax, here is the solution:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
      let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
      return cell
}
```